# Windows Batch script - Get folder containing another folder, but not containing a certain parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

In order to get all directories in drive `C:\` that contain a directory called `".svn"` I simply use the following batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D /R C:\ %%X IN (*) DO IF EXIST "%%X\.SVN" (ECHO "%%X")
```

This works! But from the result **I would also like to remove the directories that have a parent directory already containing a `.svn` directory**.

Example, let's say we have the following tree

```
C:\
C:\hello\
C:\babe\.svn
C:\babe\cool\.svn
C:\world\.svn
C:\zulu
```

My batch file above would return this list (all directories containing `.svn` folder)

```
C:\babe
C:\babe\cool
C:\world
```

I would like the batch to return only

```
C:\babe
C:\world
```

Without `C:\babe\cool` because the `.svn` directory was already found in parent directory `C:\babe`

Comment: Using dir should be faster in enumerating the .svn folders. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /ad /b /s .svn') do echo %%~fA`  As for filtering out the children I do not have a quick solution off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /D /R C:\ %%X IN (*) DO  @IF EXIST "%%X\.SVN" IF NOT EXIST "%%X\..\.SVN" (ECHO "%%X")
```